# dynamically show font awesome icon based on the http response value angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Team,

Based on my api value i need to show a lock icon to a material fields.

Here is my api output where there is a property call lock: **True** if it is **True** There should be a lock icon for the fields

Currently Iam showing in static for all the fields.

[image]

Here is my api where there is a property call Locked currently the value is true based on the value lock icon should come here is my current code

HTML code

```
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>List Items</mat-label>
        <select matNativeControl required formControlName="title">
            <option value="Mr">Mr.
            </option>
            <option value="Mrs">Mrs.
            </option>
            <option value="Ms">Ms.
            </option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss.
            </option>
        </select>
        <span *ngif="isLocked" class="fa fa-lock lock_field"></span>
    </mat-form-field>
```

I was trying to use Ngif in my ts I have created boolean call **isLocked** initially i set it as false. I thought to put in ngoninit when the page loads that time I am trying to incorporate my condition in my below code

Here is my ts code

```
  getFieldData() {
const data = {
  module: this.data.entityName,
  entity: this.data.entityFormName
};

if (data.module && data.entity) {
  // if (!((data.module === undefined || null) && (data.entity === undefined || null))) {
  this.settingService.getFormData(this.fields, data.module, data.entity).subscribe((response) => {
    this.fieldData = response;       
    
  })
}
```

}

Here is the api code

```
  getFormData(data: any, module, entity): Observable<FormData[]> {
    const formData = "/fields/getModulesEntity?module=" + module + '&entity=' + entity;
    return this.http.get<FormData[]>(formData);
  }
```

Here is my api output.

[image]

Comment: I don't see how is the property `isLocked` updated after the API call. 
And it's difficult to recognize what is the issue. I see the description of what was tried on, while I miss the part on what is not working as desired.

Comment: That is happened from backend

Comment: @IAfanasov What I thought is whenever the page loads based on the api call from angular in the ngoninit if the islocked property available as true the icon should show else no icon

Comment: I'm sorry, it's getting more and more blurry to me (: I don't recognize what is the issue, what is the expected behaviour and what is the actual one

Comment: can you try like this <span *ngif="fieldData.locked" class="fa fa-lock lock_field"></span>

Comment: @a.prakash thanks for your reply but icon is not showing can you please help me here

Comment: can you create example code in the https://stackblitz.com/ so that it can be easier to understand and rectify

Comment: @a.prakash hi is that possible can we have a separate chat to discuss this